# Spring Global CORS configuration not working but Controller level config does

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-headers, cors, cross-domain

I am trying to configure CORS globally via `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` shown below. To test I am hitting my API endpoint via a small node app I created to emulate an external service. When I try this approach the response does not contain the correct headers and fails with

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/query/1121. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:333' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Global Config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/api/query/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
        }
}
```

However when I utilize the `@CrossOrigin` annotation like so it works just fine responding with the proper headers.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowCredentials = "true", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/query", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class QueryController {
   ......
}
```

Produces

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:333
```

What am I missing to make the global config work (followed instructions here https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).  I feel like I'm missing something simple since annotating the controller works just fine.

Comment: Maybe `.allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*")` are redundant in global configuration

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am also having this issue. Tried answers below but didnt work for me...

Comment: @Will I was in the same boat as you, but managed to get something working. Have a look at my answer on here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55629589/5877810

Answer (score 25):

In order for the global CORS config to work, the client must add these two headers in the OPTIONS request.

```
Origin: http://host.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
```

However the @CrossOrigin annotation requires just the "Origin" header.
Your client probably adds the "Origin" header but is missing the "Access-Control-Request-Method".....thats why it works for you with the @CrossOrigin, but doesn't with the global config.

Comment: I'm getting `Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method"`, chrome ` 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: The client can't do this if it's code running in a web browser.

Answer (score 11):

you didn't declared method in it which is by default accept only get method.
try `registry.allowedMethods("*");`

Comment: I am facing the same issue with POST method. it solved by adding allowedmethods.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and after setting the **maxAge** attribute everything started working ok!

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer CORSConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                    .maxAge(-1)   // add maxAge
                    .allowCredentials(false);
        }
    };
}
```

if you check the **CrossOrigin** annotation it has a default value assigned to that attribute

```
/**
 * <p>By default this is set to {@code 1800} seconds (30 minutes).
 */
long maxAge() default -1;
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the Spring Global CORS configuration to work, after experiencing the exact problem documented in this issue. I had to do 2 things:

1. allowedOrigins cannot be * if allowCredentials is true. This is documented at Mozilla.org
2. Remove mvc:annotation-driven from the spring XML. Cannot have BOTH the XML config and @EnableWebMvc. The global class won't work without @EnableWebMvc, thus mvc:annotation-driven must be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been having the exact same issue, with none of the solutions in this thread working. I've managed to solve it with the following:

A new configuration bean:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilterConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
      config.setAllowCredentials(true);
      config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
      config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "OPTIONS", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT"));
      config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
      return new CorsFilter(source);
  }
}
```

A modification to my web.xml to add a new filter for all URLs:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Obviously you can modify the cors config accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**I faced similar issue. I changed the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to WebMvcConfigurationSupport  and it started working.**

In addition to this I also moved the RequestMappingHandlerMapping defined in xml configuration file to java configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and none of methods seemed to work (except using `@CrossOrigin` annotation for each controller). I followed [Bharat Singh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957181/613118) solution above and after some debugging of Spring Framework internals - here's what worked for me (**Spring Boot 2.0.6 + Spring Framework 5.0.10**):

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addCorsMappings(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry)
 */
@Override
protected void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    //NOTE: servlet context set in "application.properties" is "/api" and request like "/api/session/login" resolves here to "/session/login"!
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
        .allowedOrigins("*")
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .allowCredentials(false);
    }
}
```

Initially when I used `"/api/**"` mapping it was configured within Spring, but since the application was deployed with `"/api"` context - requests like `"/api/session/login"` were internally mapped to `"/session/login"` and such mapping in CORS configuration was not found - please pay attention to that!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was banging my head on this one for ages. I use `server.servlet.context-path` to set my API prefix to `/api` and that was totally breaking the cors mapping! So frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem working on a Spring mvc application (not Spring Boot).
The only way I could solve the problem was to explicitly add a cors filter to the spring security filter chain:

```
public class MySecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

  protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    final FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", corsFilter());
    corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
  }

  protected CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(CrossOrigin.DEFAULT_ORIGINS));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "OPTIONS", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(CrossOrigin.DEFAULT_ALLOWED_HEADERS));
    config.setAllowCredentials(CrossOrigin.DEFAULT_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS);
    config.setMaxAge(CrossOrigin.DEFAULT_MAX_AGE);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return new CorsFilter(source);
  }

}
```

Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapping definition is missing a `*`:

```
registry.addMapping("/api/query/**")
```

Without that extra `*`, this configuration is not mapped to the `/api/query/1121` request path (but it would work on `/api/query/5`).

Comment: Thank you for your response,  I also tried `"/api/query/**"` and it didn't work.  Originally I even had a 'hello world' type implementation with `registry.addMapping("/**")` and that didn't make a difference.. do I have to somehow specify that it is on port 8080? I don't even know ... it looks like it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to configure CORS globally via WebMvcConfigurerAdapter shown yours with log.
And I found log message but it got error like

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myurl' from origin 'some origin' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Controll-Allow-Origin' header is presnet on the requested resource.

My Case was also good at @CrossOrigin but not in globally configure.
I hope this will be helped.

The reason is web.xml.

1.
I have <context:component-scan base-package="some base-package">
but class WebConfig is not in 'some base-package' package, It's in the upper package.
I moved WebConfig to 'some base-package' package and

2.
I removed <mvc:annotation-driven /> because I have already have @EnableWebMvc in WebConfig class.

It works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue like this, every time it shows Cors policy error while i am trying to access an endpoint

that was due to the change in SecurityConfig class i have added Authority role as "ADMIN" and everytime adding this frontend not able to access the endpoint

So i added cors(Customizer.withDefaults())

```
   @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults()) 
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/user/register", "/login", "/image").permitAll() // Allow access to public endpoints
            .antMatchers("/user/view-all-user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN") // Require authentication for protected endpoint
            .anyRequest().permitAll() // Allow access to all other endpoints
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
}
```

this fixed my issue with the CORS policy.