# how to call spring boot api from angular in apache

Tags: java, angular, spring, apache, spring-boot

I want to call an api in the spring boot from my angular file
For example:profile.service.ts

```
  private baseUrl = '/users';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getProfile(id: number): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}` + '/load/' + `${id}`);
  }
```

and java file is : UsersController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {
    @Autowired
    private IUsersService iUsersService;

    @GetMapping("/list/grid")
    public Iterable<UsersViewModel> getAllEmployees() {
        return Dozer.mapList(iUsersService.getAll(), UsersViewModel.class);
    }

    @GetMapping("/load/{id}")
    public UsersViewModel getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long userId){
        return Dozer.mapClass(iUsersService.findById(userId).get(),UsersViewModel.class);
    }
```

The server is used for Angular is Apache and spring-boot port is 8090.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class UsersController {
...
}
```

the only implementation detail worth noting here is the use of the `@CrossOrigin` annotation. As the name implies, the annotation enables Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on the server.

This step isn’t always necessary. Since we are deploying our Angular frontend to http://localhost:4200 and our Boot backend to http://localhost:8090, the browser would otherwise deny requests from one to the other.

Good to refer: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

Comment: @seyedaliziaei Cool. What is the issue you are facing ? Check the logs. Might be CORS issue. `@CrossOrigin` will help resolve if it is CORS,.

Comment: @seyedaliziaei what do you mean by global ? are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980914/spring-global-cors-configuration-not-working-but-controller-level-config-does

Comment: please help me. crossorigin work for port 4200 but not working for port 80
when build angular to use in server

Comment: @seyedaliziaei If you are using default Apache 80 port the URL will be `http://localhost` without a specific port (as http default port is 80). Configure the Apache on some other port. In order for Access-Control-Allow-Origin permissions you need a valid port and URL like `http://domain:port/` to do that. Please refer https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/blocked-by-cors-policy-the-access-control-allow-origin-mean-stack for more information